# Is there a hotkey for Visual Studio's Navigation Bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm aware that if I navigate to Tools>Options>Text Editor>(language)>Display I can check "Navigation bar" to show this bar.

My question is, what's the keyboard shortcut for it?

(I'm pretty sure there is one, because during a flurry of misguided keystrokes earlier on, I managed to make it disappear, and of course "Undo" didn't undo that change. Welcome to Visual Studio.)

The Navigation Bar is the item highlighted in yellow below:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: what do you mean by nav bar? can you post a screen shot of which area you mean

Comment: @DarthTommy a screenshto would be problematic right now, but the item in question is found directly above the source code window, and consists of three drop-down boxes allowing you to select a project, a scope, and a class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy shortcut to select the Navigation Bar:

[image: enter link description here]

But there is no out-of-the-box shortcut to show/hide it.  Maybe you have an extension installed which provides this feature?